# How to Bind storyboard?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-7

I have two Storyboards as follows.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="ToRed">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"                                          >
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Red"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="Transparent"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ToGreen">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"                                           >
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="#FF14A514"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9" Value="Transparent"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

And i need to apply these storyboards to background property of a Border control according to a property in my VM. Can i wrap these in a style and bind it to th property? 
Without Storyboard  I do something like this

```
<Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue">
<Border.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Direction,
        Converter={StaticResource dirToColConvertor}}"/>
</Border.Background>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by combining the answer of **vinod8812** and custom attached properties(As mentioned here: http://umairsaeed.com/2010/04/22/custom-attached-properties-in-silverlight). I changed each story boards into visual states and bind it to my viewmodel  using attached properties.

Answer (score 0):

To change the state of a control you have to call

VisualStateManager.GoToSate(yourcontrol,statename,IsTransition).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there is way to do this in xaml?

Comment: You can use triggers but you need to have an event to switch between states. You can check below link http://www.joemarini.com/tutorials/tutorialpages/xamlpropertytriggers.php